# Plot traveling wave solution of sine-Gordon equation

Tags: plotting

The solution I want to represent graphically is given by the traveling wave solution to the sine-Gordon equation:

`u(x,t)=4*arctan[Exp[(x-c*t)/sqrt(1-c^2)]`

where the parameter `c` lies in (0,1) and can be adjusted by a slider. In particular, I want to show the dynamics of the traveling wave. Please show me the appropriate code for this. Thank you

Comment: `u[x_, t_, c_] := 4*ArcTan[Exp[(x - c*t)/Sqrt[1 - c^2]]];Manipulate[Plot3D[u[x, t, c], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}], {c, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Please review your Mathematica syntax. arctan and sqrt are not Mathematica functions, and you use square brackets in Mathematica for function calls.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax help. I am not seeking a 3D plot though, but a representation of the dynamics of the traveling wave.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

### Code

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[4*ArcTan[Exp[(x - c*tmax)/Sqrt[1 - c^2]]], {x, 0, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red],
 {{c, .1, "c"}, 0, .99, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tmax, .01, "time"}, .01, 100, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c, tmax}
 ]
```

### 3D version

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[4*ArcTan[Exp[(x - c*tmax)/Sqrt[1 - c^2]]], {x, 0, 30}, {t, 0, 
   100}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 10}}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  AxesLabel -> {"time", "x", "f(x,t)"}],
 {{c, .04, "c"}, .01, .99, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tmax, .01, "time"}, .01, 100, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c, tmax}
 ]
```